# linux -- concurrently reading/writing from/to a file

Tags: linux, file-io

Linux is strange for me, I am thinking how to code my program to safely operate linux files.
what aspects should I regard if my program operate(open, read or write) to a file(normal file or dev file and so on) that is being operated by other process.
can you give me some ideas, or suggest me any helpful articles/links ?

Comment: Reading your first sentence, one can safely assume that you haven't seen anything but windows from a programming perspective yet :-) I assure you, it is windows that is strange in many aspects, all other OS (including linux) are pretty normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple rule: If every one is reading, let them read, but if some one is writing as well in between, always use locks. Check [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) for details and example. 
For unix, even if file is locked file open would not fail. A try for advisory lock needs to be done.  Something like this would do it:

```
err = lockf(fd, F_TLOCK, 0);
if (err < 0)
    /* err = sharing error */;
```

Comment: Might want to mention `flock()` is advisory only right?

Comment: @dlamotte, I didn't understand. isn't this sufficient for synchronizing reads and writes?

Comment: "flock - apply or remove an advisory lock on an open file", ie: you can still write to the file, you have to use functions that listen to the lock and/or manually check the state before writing to the file.

Comment: Yup correct. Thanks for correcting.