# Server handling multiple clients - C Systems Programming

Tags: c, linux, client-server

I have server, containing a file.txt.  I have multiple clients which can read/write to this file(found on the server).  I wish to lock other write requests, when a write request is being handled. However, read requests are never locked.  Does someone know, which is best to handle such race conditions?  I am thinking that I can tackle this by having a struct for each client in the server, where each struct contains the "ip address of the client", and a "flag for enabling write to the client" and some sort of mutexes.  I hope I was clear enough :) Appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want [reader-writer locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). The fact that the actual readers and writers are remote clients is a minor detail, since the actual readers and writers will simply be threads on the server side.

The linked wikipedia articles mentions `pthread_rwlock_t`, which is defined by POSIX and should be available through [pthreads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html) on modern Linux distributions.

**Update**: Based on the OP's comment, he is trying to synchronize file access across processes. This implies that he should be using [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock), with the caveats mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230147/391161).

Comment: I understand, however the server is actually a concurrent server, i.e. I am using fork() to create child processes to handle the multiple clients. Therefore I am not using threads. Should it be the same reader-write lock merlin2011?  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @user3770009, You will have to look at file-based synchronization methods if you need to synchronize across processes.

Comment: Does it make sense to use Monitors merlin?http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mbiskup/presentations/Synchronizing%20Threads%20and%20Processes.pdf

Comment: @user3770009, If you can find an efficient process-level `monitor` library for `C`, then you could certainly do that if you wanted to.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting again, but do you know the actual difference between flock() and fnctl(),  it seems that one is a system call and the other is a c function....

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I have understood.  If a process is reading to a file, that is no problem as we can have multiple read processes.  However, as soon as the server has a write process, the flock() function is used to lock the file from being accessed.  Then the fcntl() is used to perform operations on the flock() such as,acquiring, releasing and checking whether there are any locks on the file.  Am i right? :)

Comment: @user3770009, It appears that I read the `flock` man page too quickly. I think you need to ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) concerning why `fnctl` appears to be a superset of `flock` functionality. :P

Comment: @user3770009, @merlin2011: [fcntl()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) locks work on properly-configured remote filesystems (including NFS and CIFS and so on; not necessarily on some of the rarer ones). [flock()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) locks either only apply locally, or are converted to fcntl() locks on the remote server -- but locally `fcntl()` and `flock()` locks are independent sets! It all boils down to a simple guide: *always use [fcntl()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) file locks in Linux for best results*.